# Undefined error jQuery ID Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble with using jQuery's ID Selector. Not sure why I am having problems with something so simple, but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is a snippet of html from my sign up page:

```
<div class="small-3 large-9 columns">
                    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="**********">
                    <div "small-3 large-offset-6 colums">
                        <div class="passwordStrength">
                            <p>
                                <strong>Password strength:</strong>
                                <span id="passwordRating">Strong</span>
                            </p>
                            <div class="meter" id="passwordBar">
                                <span id="strengthBar" class="strong" style="width: 255px;"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and here is a snipped of javascript from my signUpValidation.js

```
$(function(){
var form = $('#signUp'),
    email = $('#email'),
    password = $('#password'),
    address = $('#address');

if (password.value().length < 8) {
    updateBar(0);
}
```

I am getting the following error in the javascript console:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'password.value()')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That is a strange error to be getting .. what browser?

Comment: @ExplosionPills It is not a strange error. It is a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is val() not value(). [Look at the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I changed it to val() and the error is gone. But it still wasn't working and when I tried to see the val() in the javascript console I got this...

var pass = $('password')
undefined

Comment: Are you missing the #?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not... I can't think of what could be causing this, especially since I'm just getting the element $('#password') and it is clearly defined in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val()`, .value isn't a jQuery method. See more on the api site [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript we use `.value` property,
in jQuery we need to use `.val()` method:

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("password").value
```

jQuery

```
$('#password').val()
```